# Should I use customized method or customized accumulate function

Tags: drools

If I want to compute latest X (e.g. 100) value's average, and this average is within (y, z) value, I think I can only create customized method? customized accumulate function will not work since accumulate function(getResult(Serializable context)) can only accept one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you got the impression that `accumulate` only takes a single parameter. You should refer to the official [Drools documentation](https://docs.drools.org/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/), not random posts on the internet since they're generally wrong.

This is how the documentation describes the `accumulate` function:

> **accumulate**
>
> Use this to iterate over a collection of objects, execute custom actions for each of the elements, and return one or more result objects (if the constraints evaluate to true). This element is a more flexible and powerful form of the collect condition element. You can use predefined functions in your accumulate conditions or implement custom functions as needed. You can also use the abbreviation acc for accumulate in rule conditions.
>
> Use the following format to define accumulate conditions in rules:
>
> `accumulate( <source pattern>; <functions> [;<constraints>] )`

Using this, and the built-in `average` function, we can come up with something like this:

```
rule "Example"
when
  accumulate( SensorReading( $temperature: temperature );
              $avg : average( $temperature );
              $avg > 30, $avg < 35 )
then
  // only triggers when temperature average is between 30 and 35
end
```

Here, we're going to accumulate over `SensorReading` objects, taking the average `temperature`, and only triggering the right hand side when the average is between 30 and 35.

Comment: Thank you. I know above should work, but you miss my other important requirement (latest X (e.g. 100)). If you above example, how do you write the drools if you want to read the latest 100 SensorReading, and then compute those latest 100 SensorReading's temperature

Comment: Depends on what your system is and how it's configured. If you have an event stream then expire them or use temporal operators. If you're in cloud mode then only pass in the last 100.  I ignored the "last 100" part because there's plenty of ways to do it; it's super dependent on your application, configuration, and models (none of which you have shared); and it really has nothing to do with the accumulate function.

Comment: I know customized accumulate function can support last X (100) SensorReading. Can you write new drools rule by using those two accumulate functions